# Ratchet Websocket in a Port forwarded machine

Tags: php, websocket, port, portforwarding

im currently working on ratchet websocket and having a roadblock.

I have a machine running ubuntu 16.04 with an IP of 192.168.150.72 and this IP is connected to a router that is port forwarding it to my 192.168.150.72, the public IP is 202.x.x.x:1080.

The problem is the web server is accessible but the websocket is having an error regarding `

> The URL 'ws://x.x.x.x:1080:5050' is in valid

my websocket port is 5050 and th 1080 is the port for port forwarding.
how can i fix this issue regarding the websocket behaviour with port forwarding.

Hope u guys can help.
Thanks in advance.

`

Answer (score 0):

Your WS URL is invalid because it contains two port definitions: first 1080 then 5050. Based on your question it seems you already have set forwarding for HTTP: traffic coming on port 1080 forwarded to your web server port 80.

You need a similar, but another forwarding rule to pass WS traffic. For example, to forward incoming traffic on port 5050 to your local server WS port.
I suggest you to check your router configuration and set up a similar rule for WS as you now have for HTTP.